# Proper way of adding some information about product price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am writing a simple WooComerce plugin. This is the first time I work with WordPress so my question may be quite noobish.

The plugin should just provide some additional information about product price, which is approximate price in local currency (based on visitors location).

[image]

Pseudo dummy code:

```
add_action(
    'woocommerce_get_price_html', 
    function append_local_price($content, $product) {
        return $content . ' <span class="amount-local-price">Approx. (RSD 3,804)</span>';
    }, 
    10, 
    2
);
```

Dummy implementation, formatting and other issue aside, since that is not my focus in this question, what is the proper way of hooking into WooCommerce workflow in this case?

Because what I see as a pros of this approach is that you just install plugin and it works, zero configuration. But downsides are html rendering is not easily configurable (css class etc...) and you cannot control when it is applied.

Is some kind of short code more appropriate in this case?

This will require editing the theme in order to get local price shown, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than not using an anonymous function (a named function can be removed), I don't see a problem with your current approach. You can use a very minimal stylesheet or even non at all and leave styles to the themes. As far as html content, you can run yours through a filter so that people can modify it if desired. Don't forget to make your strings translation-ready.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'so_31702808_local_price' );
function so_31702808_local_price( $content, $product) {
        $local_price = "RSD 3,804"; // retrieved from your API
        $local_price_html = apply_filters( 'so_31702808_local_price_html', ' <span class="amount-local-price">'. $sprintf( __e( 'Approx. (%s)', 'your-text-domain'), $local_price ) .'</span>', $local_price, $product );
        return $content . $local_price_html;
    }, 

);
```

If the local price does not come back formatted locally, then you can use `wc_price()` with its args to format it as needed.

Comment: If this is the answer then could you accept it? Or clarify your question further?

Comment: Yes, I am just thinking if there is some way to give more control to plugin users. Like when it is shown etc..

Comment: That sounds like a new question, but you *could* introduce a checkbox in the product metabox. However, it seems like global on/off would be more useful to users. Either you need this functionality or you don't. I can't imagine needing it only on a few items.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about global one too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always enqueue your own css that will point to whatever content you added with hooks.

Hooks in woocommerce can be frustrating, trying to figure out what goes where, but as you've said, the upside is that you can just add what you need where you need it. And you can append element with a specific class in it that you can target with your css and style appropriately.

About controlling it when it's applied I think that it's up to woocommerce to determine that, so you don't really have a choice. Not sure how you'd go about using a shortcode. I mean you can add it via `add_action` by hooking somewhere, but I'm not sure what you'd get by it, seeing that you can just do the same thing by hooking into the desired place.

As for theme editing for local price I don't think you need to do this. Woocommerce has two functions [get_woocommerce_currency()](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-get_woocommerce_currency.html#_get_woocommerce_currency) and [get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-get_woocommerce_currency.html#_get_woocommerce_currency_symbol) that should help you determine the currency set by the user on his site.

The 'hard' part is configuring all the currency exchange, because the relations between them change. So you'll need some kind of API that tracks this and returns the relation for you, that you can later on apply to your plugin.

This is more like a long comment than a real answer tbh...

Comment: Honestly, a real answer would be off-topic ;) The question is more akin to how to build a plugin that does currency exchanges rather than the specific questions being asked.

Comment: @Aibrean Absolutelly not. I already have a library that returns local price, something like `mylibrary.convertToLocalMoney(35, 'USD')` and it returns `[3804, 'RSD']`. So question is not related to how to do currency exchange. Real answer should just suggest preferred way of doing it from UX point of view in woocomerce. User installs plugin and then edists theme to appear local price, or it just works out of the box etc...

Comment: @dingo_d Thanks for your answer. As I said in my previous comment, forget about currency exchange, I fetch this from public APIs available (Google, Yahoo...). I know I can inject css, but it depends on theme installed. If I provide my CSS, it may not fit into currently installed theme. I don't think I should manage design here, but rather provide data. Hm, not sure, I hope you see my worries. Regarding shortcode, I think it is should be added using `add_shortcode` rather then `add_action`, but I got this thin wrong, since shortcodes can be used in posts and pages, which is not my case.

Comment: Seems as though it should be based on the customer's billing address. Or at some point, the customer chooses their location (or has the option to change). A shortcode wouldn't be necessary if you are adding an action.

`add_action ('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'yourfunction')`
`function yourfunction(){//Then write your function}` Your code is close, but not exactly right.

Comment: @umpirsky I'd still add my own css in the plugin, that the user can then modify to fit his own design. What you need to do is to provide with the bare minimum that will look good on any theme. So no fancy blemishes etc. Focus on the functionality of the plugin. Also with woocommerce it's tricky, because most themes (at least shop themes on Themeforest) have modified the templates in some way. So some hook that you used for hooking your filter or action to may not be present in all themes (that is to say: use the ones that you're sure are needed for shop to function). That's how I'd do it.

Comment: @dingo_d I see. But I would not worry about some themes not use my hook. If it works in default theme, it's non standard themes problem. I will for sure provide hook and doc so users can add it easily with one line of code by editing their theme. I was worried about modifying standard output of some filter by appending some html. But like this is a standard way of doing it in wordpress community. Is it?

Comment: @dingo_d I was actually thinking about detecting visitors country based on their IP address.

Comment: Well if you're bothered that you'll change something, then definitely use `add_action`. Because action is a place where you call a function, vs filter that will modify the existing function, you can't mess up that much :D I don't know about the standard, but since woocommerce relies on hooks quite a bit, this is the way I'd go about it.